# Alpha AWUS036H, failed to increase txpower

Tags: networking, wireless

I would like to increase the tx power of my AWUS036H Wifi card, i'm trying it using those commands.

```
ifconfig wlan0 down 
iw reg set BO
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

There is no output to all those commands...

So, I check the txpower of my wireless card using iwconfig

```
$ sudo iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I tried with different txpower values, as 1, 15 or  3500, still no output or reaction

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, using CRDA and wireless-regbd ! 
https://blog.binaryfactory.ca/2012/09/setting-txpower-as-high-as-your-card-can-go/